# Apply basic bootstrap input styling to bootstrap-select select input

Tags: css, bootstrap-select

I am using bootstrap-select to add the search function to my selects in my bootstrap project.  It works great but what I can't stand about it is that it transforms the select from the default styling and basically applies the 'btn-light' style to it.  So it looks completely different than the rest of the inputs and I HATE IT and I can't figure out how to change it.

Does anyone have any ideas?  The easiest the best =)

This looks terrible!
[image]

Comment: Make sure you're importing bootstrap before your css, and use important to override specific rules. Have you tried this?

Comment: I am not using any custom CSS.  Just bootstrap 4.6.  Bootstrap renders the selects as shown on the left and right in the picture.  When I add the class for bootstrap-select to the middle select though it changed to that... I hate it.

Comment: Exactly, so add your own styles to the inputs and override the bootstrap styles by using important.

Comment: can I see your code?

Comment: I didn't want to add my own styles, I just wanted the style that was previously applied to not be affected.  I have answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

Add `data-style=''` and `data-style-base='form-control'` to the select element.